# Сетка из адаптивных (responsive) квадратов

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Мне интересно, я бы хотел создать макет с `responsive` квадратами. Каждый квадрат будет иметь **вертикальное и горизонтальное выравнивание** содержимого.

Ниже показан конкретный пример ..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перевод вопроса: [Grid of responsive squares @garethdn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20456694/7394871)

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456694/grid-of-responsive-squares/20457076#20457076

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете создать адаптивную сетку квадратов с вертикально и горизонтально центрированным контентом только с помощью CSS.

Я объясню  в пошаговом процессе, как это сделать, но сначала посмотрите здесь две демоверсии того, как  вы сможете это реализовать:

- [Grid of square images](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/MpXYr/2/embedded/result/)
- [Grid of squares with content](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/MpXYr/3/embedded/result/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь давайте посмотрим, как сделать эти причудливые `responsive` квадраты!

### 1. Создание адаптивных квадратов:

Трюк для сохранения пропорций 1:1 - `square` (или любого другого соотношения сторон) заключается в использовании процента `padding-bottom`.

*Примечание: вы можете использовать `top padding` или `top/bottom margin`, но фон элемента не будет отображаться.*

Поскольку `top padding` рассчитывается в соответствии с шириной **родительского элемента** ([см. MDN для справки](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-bottom#Values)), высота элемента будет изменяться в соответствии с его шириной.

Теперь вы можете **сохранять пропорции** в соответствии с шириной.

На этом этапе вы можете применить код:

HTML:

```
 <div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 30%;
    padding-bottom: 30%; /* = width for a square aspect ratio */
}
```

Вот простой [пример раскладки квадратов](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/MpXYr/4/) 3 * 3 с использованием кода выше

С помощью этой методики, вы можете сделать любое другое соотношение сторон, здесь приведена таблица, в которой заданы значения `bottom padding` в соответствии с соотношением сторон и шириной 30%.

```
 Aspect ratio  |  padding-bottom  |  for 30% width
------------------------------------------------
    1:1        |  = width         |    30%
    1:2        |  width x 2       |    60%
    2:1        |  width x 0.5     |    15%
    4:3        |  width x 0.75    |    22.5%
    16:9       |  width x 0.5625  |    16.875%
```

### 2. Добавление содержимого внутри квадратов

Поскольку вы не можете добавлять содержимое непосредственно внутри квадратов (это увеличит их высоту, а квадраты не будут квадратами больше), вам нужно создать дочерние элементы (для этого примера я - использую divs) внутри них с `position:abolute;`
И размещаю контент в дочерних элементах.
 Это выведет контент из потока и сохранит размер квадрата.

**Не забудьте** добавить `position:relative;` на родительских `divs`, так как `absolute children` размещаются / оцениваются относительно своего родителя.

Давайте добавим некоторый контент в нашу сетку 3x3 квадратов:

HTML:

```
<div class="square">
    <div class="content">
        .. CONTENT HERE ..
    </div>
</div>
... and so on 9 times for 9 squares ...
```

CSS:

```
.square {
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    padding-bottom: 30%; /* = width for a 1:1 aspect ratio */
    margin:1.66%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.content {
    position:absolute;
    height:80%; /* = 100% - 2*10% padding */
    width:90%; /* = 100% - 2*5% padding */
    padding: 10% 5%;
}
```

[RESULT](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/MpXYr/5/) <-- с некоторым форматированием, чтобы сделать его симпатичным!

### 3.Центрирование контента

**Горизонтально:**

Это довольно просто, вам просто нужно добавить `text-align: center` в `.content.

[RESULT](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/MpXYr/6/)

**Вертикальное выравнивание:**

Это становится серьезным! Весь фокус в том, чтобы использовать

```
display:table;
/* and */
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
```

Но мы не можем использовать `display: table;` На `.square` или `.content divs`, потому что это противоречит `position:absolute;` Поэтому нам нужно создать два дочерних элемента внутри `.content divs`. Наш код будет обновлен следующим образом:

HTML:

```
<div class="square">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="table">
            <div class="table-cell">
                ... CONTENT HERE ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
... and so on 9 times for 9 squares ...
```

CSS:

```
.square {
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    padding-bottom : 30%; /* = width for a 1:1 aspect ratio */
    margin:1.66%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.content {
    position:absolute;
    height:80%; /* = 100% - 2*10% padding */
    width:90%; /* = 100% - 2*5% padding */
    padding: 10% 5%;
}
.table{
    display:table;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.table-cell{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Мы закончили, и мы можем посмотреть на результат здесь:

**[LIVE FULLSCREEN RESULT](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/MpXYr/3/embedded/result/)**

[editable fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/MpXYr/3/)

Перевод ответа: [Grid of responsive squares @web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20457076/7394871)